# List Every Single Registry Key in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-registry, list

I am trying to either find or generate a list of all the registry keys that exist in several versions of Windows.  I have searched extensively online, without finding any such list or a command to recursively generate such a list.  Does anyone know how to get a list like this?

Comment: @Ramhound - Could you please expound on that, in the form of an answer?  If you could post the specific commands, I would much appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/11/use-powershell-to-enumerate-registry-property-values/ you would have to enumerate using a loop as a couple of of other people have mentioned. The link has examples of how to do it using PowerShell.

Comment: couldn't you just copy the hive files?

Comment: @Kernel Stearns Isn't it what option `compare` do in `reg.exe` ?

Comment: If you want a text document with all the registry paths, keys, values, and so on with a text file you can open to look at the detail, then just using the standard regedit export function to a .REG file (which is a text file) and then open it with a text editor and there you go. You can rename the extension from .reg to .txt if you wish as well.

Comment: @ITSolutions - Thanks for the comment, that was what I was looking for.  I will post it as an answer to my own question now.

Comment: "but I want a script that will go through recursively and spit out a text document that has the full path to every registry key automatically." - You should rephrase your question, so I can retract my close vote, and reverse my vote.  We are not a script writting service, but this doesn't require a script, so you don't need to (nor should you) ask for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by IT Solutions, I found the answer to this.  Below is the command line code:

```
reg.exe export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE C:\path\machine_registry.txt
reg.exe export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT C:\path\local_registry.txt
reg.exe export HKEY_CURRENT_USER C:\path\current_registry.txt
reg.exe export HKEY_USERS C:\path\users_registry.txt
reg.exe export HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG C:\path\config_registry.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

from command line:

```
reg.exe export HKLM\hardware hklm-hw.reg
reg.exe export HKLM\sam hklm-sam.reg
reg.exe export HKLM\security hklm-sec.reg
reg.exe export HKLM\software hklm-sw.reg
reg.exe export HKLM\system hklm-sys.reg

'' the same for HKCU branch
reg.exe export HKCU\folders hkcu-folders.reg
```

and so on... then parse what you want or use `compare` option to get difference

You can also use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) to compare and get `diff` between registry snapshots

To save the whole registry in text format just run `regedit.exe` and export everything from the root of registry.

If you want to do that programmatically there is already answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825555

Comment: The stack overflow link is for a question very similar to mine, but nobody ever tells the guy why his code doesn't work.  Therefore, I have a link to a script that does what I am trying to do, except that it doesn't work.

Comment: There is  official API to your subject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell!

```
Function ListSubkeys($rootKey) {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootKey -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % {
        $_.Name # Output the item's name
        ListSubkeys $_.Name # Recurse into its subkeys
    }
}
Push-Location $args[0]
ListSubkeys $args[0]
Pop-Location
```

This script defines a recursive function `ListSubkeys` and then calls it. To use it, save that code as a `.ps1` file. After following the instructions in the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info), you can run it from a PowerShell prompt like this, specifying the file name and the starting key in PowerShell path format (the trailing `\` is important):

```
.\regkeys.ps1 'HKLM:\'
```

To send the output to a file, use the `>` redirection operator, like so:

```
.\regkeys.ps1 'HKCU:\' > C:\Users\me\Documents\allmyHKCUkeys.txt
```

Note that HKCR is actually a combination of entries from places in HKLM and HKCU, so exporting it would be duplicitous.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in PS 7.4.0.

`@( 'HKLM:\', 'HKCU:\' ) | % { Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $_ 2>$null }`